# Remplazar cada valor de una cadena con datos de un array js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Remplazar cada valor de una cadena con datos de un array con js o jquery

```
var numbers = ["0:00", "0:01", "0:05"];
for (var i = numbers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

   str = "0:00 oki 0:01".split(numbers[i]).join("");
    //console.log(str);
}
console.log(str);
```

Me regresa **oki 0:01**
Y necesito que regrese solo **oki**

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que cada vuelta del bucle vuelve a procesar la cadena completa, lo que debes hacer es definir la cadena fuera del bucle.
Le agregue .trim() al final para eliminar los espacios en blanco.

```
var numbers = ["0:00", "0:01", "0:05"];
var str="0:00 oki 0:01";
for (var i = numbers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

   str = str.split(numbers[i]).join("").trim();
    //console.log(str);
}
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Si no entendi mal tu necesitas que en el string sean filtrados los elementos que coincidan con el primer array y queden solo aquellos elementos del string que no posean similitud y quitar los espacios en blanco, bueno yo no usaria un ciclo for para eso, mejor tomaria el metodo del objeto array, Array.prototype.filter para tener dicho resultado, tu codigo se veria asi:

```
var numbers = ["0:00", "0:01", "0:05"];
var str="0:00 oki 0:01";
str = str.split(' ').filter(function(value){ 
   return numbers.indexOf(value) == -1 // Si el valor no existe devolvera true por lo tanto sabremos que valores no estan en el primer array y los filtrara, esto devuelve ["oki"]
} ).join('');
console.log(str) // salida --> oki
```

Comment: Funciona con el string proporcionado, pero estás asumiendo que los datos vienen separados por espacios. No funcionaría si el string fuera `'0:00oki0:01'`

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la solución más acertada sería usar una **expresión regular** :

```js
var numbers = ["0:00", "0:01", "0:05"];
var reg = new RegExp(numbers.join('|'), 'g');
var nuevoStr = 
    '0:00 oki 0:01'
              .replace(reg, '') // Cambia los valores capturados con el RegExp
              .trim();          // Elimina los espacios en blanco
console.log(nuevoStr);
```